# C#-winforms :EXE runs only those machines in that Visual Studio installed

Tags: c#, .net, database, winforms, connection

I have used SQL SERVER 2005 & c# .net for front end & app.config file also used .
But, when i have install the exe in those system in that no Visual Studio but  framework 3.5 is present then error shows & on the other hand exe install & run quite well in those system in that already installed the VS & framework .

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[
"gdesigner.Properties.Settings.Database1ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = 
new SqlCommand("insert into abc values('"+textBox1.Text+"')",con);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("DATA INSERTED");
```

app.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="gdesigner.Properties.Settings.Database1ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: app.config file
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="gdesigner.Properties.Settings.Database1ConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>

Comment: You should post the error message you get. Is this a WinForms application or a ASP.NET application?

Comment: What error is shown? It sounds like a reference issue if it works on machines with VS installed.

Comment: Please add your config file data in the question body and format as code. It's real difficult to read in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difficult to understand without a precise error message, but I bet the error is 
that on machine without Visual Studio none has installed SQLServer Express.

Comment: u mean first i have installed the SQL SERVER 2005 in my client system then program will runs quite well ?

Comment: Visual Studio, usually install a copy of SQLServer Express to help develop database applications. Of course, on machine without VS there is an high chance that there isn't a SQLServer installed. In this case you should install manually SQLServer Express or modify your connectionstring to read/write on an already installed SQLServer (where you still need to add your database)

Answer (score 2):

Your connection string specifies connecting to a local instance of SQL Express (which is installed during VS Install, or available as a stand alone installer). Most likely the machines which do not have VS also do not have SQLExpress, so the connection fails.

To solve the problem either install SQLExpress on the machines (if you require an individual database-per-installation) or update the configuration to point back to your central/single SQL instance (if you require a single DB for all installation instances on your network)

Comment: means i have only install SQL XPRESS in those system have errors generated ?

Comment: Yes, that will solve the errors. But you need to realize that will create an individual database on each machine you install your exe on. Those databases will not share data or talk to each other. I'm not sure if that is your itention or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Visual Studio Setup Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19x10e5c.aspx) and add the necessary dependencies your applications needs (*such as SQL Express and .NET framework version*). Instead of distributing out the EXE, you would deploy it as an MSI package which also makes upgrades & uninstallations easier.

Alternately - you could perform the prerequisite installs yourself on the machines you wish to deploy your application to.